# payment method - authorize.net error Invalid request. Please check your formatting

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize

I perfectly configured the authorize.net and when I place order I get the error as "**Invalid request. Please check your formatting.**"

I have also checked the currency format in both payment method currency, and accepted currency and both are fine.

I also tried by using other cards like visa, discover ,jcb, etc but I get the same error.

When I see in the unsettled payment reports in the sandbox account no payment transactions are visible.

[image: Error code when order is placed]

The above image shows the error when "**place order**" button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time in searching i found that the error came from init.js which came from the cardinalcommerece (https://cardinaldocs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CC/pages/100401153/Error+Codes)

The solution is go to

> Stores->Configuration->Payment Method->Secure 3D->

**turn off** `Enable for Authorize.net`